# how to do js and php validation?

Tags: php, javascript

I have four text boxes name

textbox1: 
textbox2: 
textbox3: 
textbox3:

I need to validate this field by following some criteria like below :

1.If anyone put value in textbox1,he must forced to put value in textbox2.Otherwise both textbox can be empty.

2.If anyone put value in textbox3,he must forced to put value in textbox4.Otherwise both textbox can be empty.

Above this criteria,how can i make validation.

Comment: Why do you need PHp for this ?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: on which event you want to validate?

Comment: You should first try googling your problems. And giving it a try...

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.May be it will help you.

first put the css and js library.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>

<script src="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

this is your js function which will validate your form field while submit the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#ckForm").validationEngine();
});
</script>
```

Now the form

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="ckForm">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" />
    <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" class="validate[condRequired[textbox1]]" />
    <input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3" />
    <input type="text" name="textbox4" id="textbox4" class="validate[condRequired[textbox3]]" />
    <input type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Please let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'll inform you if it works.

Comment: you always welcome mate.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an example and not a final solution but if you've a few PHP and JS skills it should help you a lot.

**PHP:**

```
$Input = new Input();
$Input
    ->post("username")
        ->validate(Input::RULE_MINLENGTH, 4)
        ->validate(Input::RULE_MAXLENGTH, 20)
    ->post("email")
        ->validate(Input::RULE_NOT_EMPTY, null)
        ->validate(Input::RULE_IS_EMAIL, true)
    ->post("email2")
        ->validate(Input::RULE_EQUALS, "email")
    ->post("password")
        ->validate(Input::RULE_MINLENGTH, 1)
        ->validate(Input::RULE_MAXLENGTH, 20)
    ->post("password2")
        ->validate(Input::RULE_EQUALS, "password")
    ->post("random_text");

if (empty($_POST)) {
    // $_POST is empty, show the template!
    $Template->assign("validation_rules", $Input->get_rules_json());
    $Template->show("template.tpl");
} else {
    if ($Input->submit("post")) {
        // everything alright
        echo "No errors.";
    } else {
        echo "Errors: ";
        print_r($Input->get_errors());
    }
}
```

**Template/JavaScript:**

```
$("#form").ajaxForm({
    "beforeSubmit": function() {
        // validate
        return formValidation($("#form"), '<?php echo $this->validation_rules?>');
    }
});
```

**Edit:**
Check out this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf6o3MIcAtA

Enjoy!

Comment: i dint understand anything by your answer @Bombastic

Comment: @Wolverine: Then you should learn some PHP and Javascript basics first. :-) It's a PHP class that handles your validation. My example shows how to use it.

Comment: o yah?You think,i need to learn php basic,i am working in php 1year above.Its not possible for me to start from php basic coz i have already complete it. @Mr, Bombastic

Comment: 1 year is nothing. I'm not here to argue, but if you're not able to understand my code, than you've to learn more because my code isn't that complicated. Anyway, I edited my answer and added a video link. Check it out, it should help you for validation at the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to say to me it seems as if you require ajax. See if you can use AJAX or not for fulfilling your requirement.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment

Comment: yeah I know I actually wanted to comment but ended up writing comment as answer.

Comment: actually its not clear to me what actually Wolverine wants to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using simple java script function.

```
function validate()
{
var txtBox1= document.getElementById('textbox1');
var txtBox2= document.getElementById('textbox2');
var txtBox3= document.getElementById('textbox3');
var txtBox4= document.getElementById('textbox3');
if(txtBox1.value!=""&&txtBox2.value=="")
{
    alert("Enter a value in text box");
    txtBox2.focus();
    return;
}
if(txtBox3.value!=""&&txtBox4.value=="")
{
    alert("Enter a value in text box");
    txtBox4.focus();
    return;
}
}
```

you can call this method onchange of each text box.let me know i answer your question?